# FabricJS with Angular: Change Font Family, Size, Alignment, etc

Tags: angularjs, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS with an AngularJS application. I am able to add text to a canvas and, using the kitchensink example located [here](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/), I can perform functions such as bold, italic, underline, etc.

However, the issue I have is how to change the font family, text align, font size, etc. since when I make a selection from a dropdown for font family, no changes occur... but it works in the Kitchensink example.

I am using the Kitchensink example as I need to not only add text, but edit it once it shows on the Canvas, and this appears to have what I need.

A button (which is working) has an HTML element such as:

```
<button class="btn btn-object-action" type="button" ng-class="{'btn-inverse': isBold()}" ng-click="toggleBold()">
Bold</button>
```

Which is backed up by the following in the Controller:

```
$scope.toggleBold = function () {
setActiveStyle('fontWeight',
getActiveStyle('fontWeight') === 'bold' ? '' : 'bold');
};
```

As I stated, this works as intended. Where I am having challenges is changing something like the Font Family or Font Size in that the change is achieved without a button click. Here is sample HTML for the Font Family select from the Kitchensink example:

```
<label style="display: inline-block;" for="font-family">Font family:</label><select class="btn-object-action" id="font-family" bind-value-to="fontFamily">
<option value="arial">Arial</option>
<option value="helvetica" selected="">Helvetica</option>
<option value="myriad pro">Myriad Pro</option>
</select>
```

This is backed up by this in the controller:

```
function getActiveProp(name) {
var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
if (!object) return '';

return object[name] || '';
}

function setActiveProp(name, value) {
var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
if (!object) return;

object.set(name, value).setCoords();
canvas.renderAll();
}

$scope.getFontFamily = function () {
return getActiveProp('fontFamily').toLowerCase();
};
$scope.setFontFamily = function (value) {
setActiveProp('fontFamily', value.toLowerCase());
};

function watchCanvas($scope) {

function updateScope() {
$scope.$$phase || $scope.$digest();
canvas.renderAll();
}

canvas
.on('object:selected', updateScope)
.on('group:selected', updateScope)
.on('path:created', updateScope)
.on('selection:cleared', updateScope);
}

$scope.getSelected = function () {
return canvas.getActiveObject();
};


$scope.canvas = canvas;
$scope.getActiveStyle = getActiveStyle;

addAccessors($scope);
watchCanvas($scope);
```

I am more used to using ng-model than bind-value-to, in fact, I have never seen or used bind-value-to before in Angular apps/not sure how and if I should be using it.

My main question is how do I get the dropdowns working where if I select a value it updates per the Kitchensink example for text [here](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/)? What I am missing/is there a better way given that **my need is to add and edit stylized text.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind a change event to your select element so that when you change the select value, you execute the function that will change the font family.

bind-value-to is a custom directive in the kitchensink app so don't worry about it.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you have any sample code for how to bind a change event? Should I delete the bind-value-to?